# Jquery only works for the first time but not when it loops in ng-repeat for the second time

Tags: jquery, angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="MyTutorialApp">
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .skillp
    {
        width: 25px;
    }
    .count
    {
        background-color:#4cff00;
        border:2px #000000 solid;
        color:#4cff00;
    }
    .null
    {
        background-color:none;
        border:2px #fff solid;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('MyTutorialApp', []);
    app.controller("controller", function ($scope) {
    $scope.roles = [
    {
        id: 0,
        description: [
            {desc:'Java',proficiency:'5'},
            {desc: 'C++', proficiency: '2'}, 
            {desc: 'C#', proficiency: '4' }
        ]
            }];
            });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
if ($("#skill").text() == "1")
    $("#p0").addClass("count");
else if ($("#skill").text() == "2") {
    $("#p0").addClass("count");
    $("#p1").addClass("count");
}
else if ($("#skill").text() == "3") {
    $("#p0").addClass("count");
    $("#p1").addClass("count");
    $("#p2").addClass("count");
}
else if ($("#skill").text() == "4") {
    $("#p0").addClass("count");
    $("#p1").addClass("count");
    $("#p2").addClass("count");
    $("#p3").addClass("count");
}
else if ($("#skill").text() == "5") {
    $("#p0").addClass("count");
    $("#p1").addClass("count");
    $("#p2").addClass("count");
    $("#p3").addClass("count");
    $("#p4").addClass("count");
}
else
    $("#p0").addClass("null");
    $("#p1").addClass("null");
    $("#p2").addClass("null");
    $("#p3").addClass("null");
    $("#p4").addClass("null");
});
</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="controller">
    <div ng-repeat="role in roles" style="width: 622px; height: 28px;">
        <div ng-repeat="descr in role.description" style="width: 565px; height: 22px;">
            <div style="float:left;text-align:left; width: 42px;"><span>{{descr.desc}}</span></div>
                <div style="float:left;text-align:right;">
                 <span id="skill">{{descr.proficiency}}</span>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 274px; height: 19px;float:left; top: 0px; left: 0px;padding-left:10px;">
                <div class="" id="p0" style="width: 20px;float:left; color:white; top: 0px; height: 7px;border:1px black solid;margin-top:5px;">.</div>
                <div class="" id="p1" style="width: 20px;float:left; color:white; top: 0px; height: 7px;border:1px white solid;margin-top:5px;">.</div>
                <div class="" id="p2" style="width: 20px;float:left; color:white; top: 0px; height: 7px;border:1px white solid;margin-top:5px;">.</div>
                <div class="" id="p3" style="width: 20px;float:left; color:white; top: 0px; height: 7px;border:1px white solid;margin-top:5px;">.</div>
                <div class="" id="p4" style="width: 20px;float:left; color:white; top: 0px; height: 7px;border:1px white solid;margin-top:5px;">.</div>
            </div>
      </div><br/>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am having trouble with my code, what I want to accomplish is that when the text inside the
{{descr.proficiency}} is "1" for example, it will fill one div with a green background-color. If two, fill two divs with green background-color and so on.

When I ran my code, it seems the jquery I created is only working for the first time it looped in the ng-repeat="descr in role.description"

My result is:
example: Java 5  -----                                                                             
               C++   2  
               C#    4

Note: - represents the div filled withgreen color.

But what I want is to display the bars for each desc.

Expected is:
example: Java 5  -----                                                                             
               C++   2  --
               C#    4  ----

Can you assist me? What am I missing?

Comment: This works and it is very helpful for me to further understand what directives can do. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that without using jQuery.

**Solution 1:** Ideally, you should use this solution that creates the divs using `ng-repeat` on descr.proficiency:

```
<div style="width: 274px; height: 19px; float: left; 
top: 0px; left: 0px; padding-left:10px;">
    <div class="count" ng-repeat="n in [] | range:(descr.proficiency)" 
    style="width: 20px;float:left; color:white; top: 0px; height: 7px;
    border:1px black solid;margin-top:5px;">.</div>                
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.filter('range', function() {
    return function(input, total) {
        total = parseInt(total);
        for (var i=0; i<total; i++)
            input.push(i);
        return input;
    };
});
```

**Solution 2:** Apply the CSS class conditionally:

```
<div style="width: 274px; height: 19px;float:left; top: 0px; left: 0px;
padding-left:10px;">
    <div class="{{(descr.proficiency==1 || descr.proficiency==2 || 
    descr.proficiency==3 || descr.proficiency==4 || 
    descr.proficiency==5) && 'count'}}" 
    id="p0" style="width: 20px;float:left; color:white; top: 0px; height: 7px;
    border:1px black solid;margin-top:5px;">.</div>

    <div class="{{(descr.proficiency==2 || descr.proficiency==3 || 
    descr.proficiency==4 || descr.proficiency==5) && 'count'}}" 
    id="p1" style="width: 20px;float:left; color:white; top: 0px; height: 7px;
    border:1px white solid;margin-top:5px;">.</div>

    <div class="{{(descr.proficiency==3 || descr.proficiency==4 || 
    descr.proficiency==5) && 'count'}}" 
    id="p2" style="width: 20px;float:left; color:white; top: 0px; height: 7px;
    border:1px white solid;margin-top:5px;">.</div>

    <div class="{{(descr.proficiency==4 || descr.proficiency==5) && 'count'}}" 
    id="p3" style="width: 20px;float:left; color:white; top: 0px; height: 7px;
    border:1px white solid;margin-top:5px;">.</div>

    <div class="{{(descr.proficiency==5) && 'count'}}" 
    id="p4" style="width: 20px;float:left; color:white; top: 0px; height: 7px;
    border:1px white solid;margin-top:5px;">.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider writing a directive for this. I've created a [demo on Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VkZaaTgWevVeyJ3UUEgN?p=preview).

In the demo I have created a directive called `level` with attribute `value`. HTML which renders the list of skills with their levels is very simple:

```
<div ng-repeat="skill in skills">
  {{ skill.desc  }}: <level value="{{ skill.proficiency }}"></level>
</div>
```

Note that I have simplified your `$scope` a little bit for demonstration purposes (there is just the skills array, each skill has description and proficiency).

Here's a directive implementation:

```
app.directive('level', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
      attrs.$observe('value', function(newValue) {
        // value attribute has changed, re-render
        var value = Number(newValue);
        element.children().remove();
        while (value > 0) {
          element.append('<span>x</span>')
          value--;
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

There are several points worth pointing out in directive implementation:

- Directive watches the level attribute and re-renders the directive content every time the level attribute changes
- jQuery is optional and I don't use it here. Angular has its own lightweight jQuery implementation called [jqLite](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/docs/api/angular.element).
- I generate `<span>x</span>` for each level point to demonstrate that I can generate HTML.

To learn more about directives check out [Angular's guide on directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). I have also found [Misko Hevery's talk on Directives](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WqmeI5fZcho) to be really useful.